# Python subprocess cannot find programs

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to call a java application from a python script. When Java was installed, a `java.exe` program was added to the `c:\windows\system32` folder, this folder is included in the `PATH` environment variable.

Running

```
import subprocess
import os
subprocess.call("java") //or "c:/windows/system32/java.exe"
```

results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 893, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden
```

Investigating a bit further, I tried running a console (`cmd`) using the same way. When doing a `dir c:\windows\system32` in that console, `java.exe` is not listed! In fact, a whole bunch of files are not listed compared to running the same command from a "normal" console.

I have no clue what might be causing this, since the exact same workflow does work on another computer. I know I can circumvent the problem by directly calling the java installation, instead of the executable in the system32 folder, but I'd like to find the root of this problem.

This problem is occurring in a Quantum Gis plugin. Quantum Gis uses an included python installation, so I did not install python myself. The python version listed is "2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on Win32". I am running Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: `java.exe` is not in `C:\Windows\System32`. It's in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre<some_nubmer>\bin`

Comment: After installing java (JDK 1.7.0_15), there is indeed a `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\bin\java.exe`, but there is also one in the `System32` folder. When running `where java`, the system32 one is listed.

Comment: Didn't now JDK is writing there. Anyway, your issue is answered in the answer below :)

Comment: New javas will indeed appear in system32. HOWEVER this is projected in there depending on the current app being 64 or 32-bit. If you run 32 bit python and can't see java -- it is because your 32 bit app isn't seeing it. Go to 64 bit python and you will see it.

Answer (score 4):

No, `subprocess.call("java")` can **never** result in a `NameError` being thrown.

You are running that without quotes instead:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(java)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'java' is not defined
```

A `NameError` exception is Python telling you the global name `java` is not defined *in your code*, not that the command `java` has not been found on your machine.

Comment: True, the errors for not founding the executable are `WindowsError` on Windows and `OSError` on most Linux distros.

Comment: You are right, when writing this question, I wrote down the error of a bad command. I've updated the question.

Comment: @DieterDP: In that case, the GIS plugin is altering the environment your python code is running in. Without any knowledge of that plugin, there is little we can help you with.

Comment: That was my first thought as well, which is why I ran these commands directly from a python console (using the python installed in the Quantum GIS program). It could be that that environment is changed... But I've never encountered something like that, is it even possible to "hide" a part of the OS from python? Also, I'd expect the same problem to occur on different computers then.

Comment: @DieterDP: I'm not certain what happens here in your case, but yes, software can and does create 'views' on a system. Virtual Machines, chroot environments, altered system libraries all can achieve partial or full isolation.

Comment: Assuming it's something like that: I spawned a console (ending up in a "protected view", but in there I ran a `runas /user:Administrator cmd` command. This new console also ends up in the protected view... I wouldn't expect this, but I could understand it...